# .NET Compact Framework

Tags: .net, windows-mobile

I'm using .NET CF application on a GPS enabled windows Mobile to get the GPS co-ordinates og the device. But I at times the whole application just freezes up. It's a very light weight application and I'm using Samples.Location library which comes with Windows Mobile SDK. Any suggestions why is it hanging up ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like there has been a known issue with windows mobile SDK which causes a deadlock if used with GPS library. However There is a work around, just follow the link below.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ee958066.aspx